# Zero-point energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was watching the following video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPAxzr6ihu8
@15:15 there is an inequality and I am not sure how to get the last step

$\Delta E \geq \frac{\hbar^{2}}{8m(\Delta x)^{2}} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^{2}(\Delta x)^{2}$
and substituting $\Delta x = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}$

$\Delta E \geq \frac{\hbar^{2}}{8m(\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega})} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^{2}(\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}) = \frac{\omega\hbar}{4} + \frac{\omega\hbar}{4} = \frac{\omega\hbar}{2}$

and I am supposed to get $\Delta E \geq \frac{1}{2}hf$

Comment: $\hbar\omega = hf$

Comment: Just a further note: $hf$ ~ [Joules/(cycles/sec)]*[cycles/sec] and $\hbar\omega$ ~ [Joules/(radians/sec)]*[radians/sec].  So both are equivalent depending on how you want to express frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $\omega = 2\pi f$ and $\hbar = \frac{h}{2\pi}$